# Compering number to a current month in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a data table that looks like this:

| Id | Month | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| e1 | 9 | 2 |
| e2 | 10 | 3 |
| e3 | 10 | 1 |
| e4 | 9 | 3 |

The month column is an integer. I want to get a sum of number both for October and September, but by using a reference to a current month and last month, as if the data is going to change in time.

I've tried using  `MONTH(DATE())`:

```
SELECT Sum(dt.Number)
FROM dt
WHERE dt.Month = MONTH(DATE());
```

as well as

```
WHERE CInt(dt.Month) = CInt(MONTH(DATE()));
```

But it didn't work (it's not error, it just don't return anything).
I will be greatful for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Sum(dt.Number) AS SumOfNumber
FROM dt
HAVING (((dt.Month)=Month(Date())));
```

Comment: It returns nothing just like my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `In` the current month or the previous month:

```sql
Select 
    Sum([Number]) As Total
From 
    dt
Where 
    dt.Month In (Month(Date(), (Month(Date()) + 12 - 2) Mod 12 + 1);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I've got an error. I think the problem is the data type of Month(Date()), but I have no idea how to change it to Integer, when CInt don't work.

Comment: What error? `Month(Date())` does return an integer, and it works here.

Comment: @Aleksandra *It doesn't work* is not a valid error description. Please update your post with specific error details.